# problema al redirigir con un middleware en Laravel

Tags: laravel, middleware

Buenas tardes estoy utilizando `Laravel` y estoy implementando un `Middleware` con el objetivo de que realice una consulta en la base de datos y dependiendo de que si un valor es `null` me redirija hacía una página para poder llenar estos datos e insertarlos, el middleware que hice es el siguiente:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\Contadores;
use Closure;

class MasConfiguraciones
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $contador = Contadores::find(4);

    if (is_null($contador->cantidad)) {
        return redirect('otrasconfiguraciones');
    }
    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

y de esta manera lo puse en el web.php:

```
Route::middleware(['configuracion', 'masconfiguraciones', 'auth', 'noGoBack', ])->group(function ()
```

pero cuando actualizo la página en la que estoy ubicado, lo lógico sería que al existir el valor de `null` en el campo `$contador->cantidad` se redirija hacia la ruta que especifique pero esta sucediendo sucede esto que muestro en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es que cuando realiza la verificación de la condición me sucede eso. Por que puede estar sucediendo esto, que es lo que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 0):

Considera lo siguiente:

Usar el método `find()` te estará retornando 2 posibles resultados:

- Un objeto con las propiedades si es que la consulta si generó resultados
- `null` si es que la consulta no retornó valores

Por tanto debes considerar lo siguiente:

Si el resultado de la consulta fue `null` e intentas hacer lo siguiente:

```
is_null($contador->propiedad);
```

Te dará como resultado este error:

> Trying to get a property of non an object

Lo cual como te das cuenta rompe la lógica en tu código, entonces se me ocurre que pruebes del modo siguiente:

**Opción**

Solamente identificando si el resultado de la consulta es `null` pero sin tratar de querer acceder a una propiedad, ya que si es nulo entonces esa propiedad no existe.

```
if (is_null($contador)) {
 .................................
}
```

Comment: me sigue haciendo lo mismo que muestro en la imagen que expuse en la pregunta. No tengo idea de que es lo que sucede

Answer (score 0):

Colegas acabo de detectar cual era el problema. Como bien expuse en mi `web.php` tenía todas las rutas de mi proyecto dentro de este grupo de Middleware:

`Route::middleware(['configuracion', 'masconfiguraciones', 'auth', 'noGoBack', ])->group(function ()`

y la ruta que llama a la vista a la cual me quiero dirigir estaba dentro de ese grupo y por tanto siempre iba a ser un ciclo sin fin porque cuando fuera a llamar esa ruta sucedería lo mismo.